# AttributeError / 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

## Hello, i'm newest in django and python and this error take a lot of my time and i don't now where is the problem

```
views.py

    currentUser = request.user

        assert isinstance(category.objects, object)
        categoryData = category.objects.get(categoryName=category)
        newListing = Listing(`            title=title,
            description=description,
            imageurl = imageurl,
            price=price,
            Category=categoryData,
            owner=currentUser
        )
        newListing.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(index)) 

models.py
```

```
    class Listing(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=2560)
        imgUrl = models.CharField(max_length=100000)
        price = models.FloatField()
        isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,     related_name="user")
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True,       related_name="categort")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryName
```

I try many solutions from here but it's fail

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize "Category.objects" on this line

`categoryData = category.objects.get(categoryName=category)`

Make it

`categoryData = Category.objects.get(categoryName=category)`

Comment: This is a new eror after i do it ==> Category matching query does not exist.

Comment: that means there is no category with the name specified in the 'category' variable.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code you provided, it seems like you use same variable name `category` for both model name and (slug?) parameter. Must be solved with slug parameter name change. (P.S. `category` in object filtering and `category.objects`)

**EDIT**

You also always have to catch an exception when you use `objects.get(...)` method, as it throws DoesNotExist exception if it can't find any object. **NOTE!** you should only use this method if you are completely sure that it only return one object from db. Else you have to also catch MultipleObjectsReturned exception.

Also consider using [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404). But keep in mind, that it only catches DoesNotExist exception.

Examples of usage:

```py
try:
    Category.objects.get(**kwargs)
except Category.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('No categoryfound')  # or return HttpResponse with status code 404
except Category.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    ...  # etc
```

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: edited for you last question